# Sort a dictionary in python by values but maintaining the key order for equal values

Tags: python, sorting, python-2.7, dictionary

Lets say there is a dictionary

```
d = {"P1":77,"P2":89,"P3":77}
```

I want to print the results in following form

P2: 89

P1: 77

P3: 77

i.e. sorting by dictionary values and for equal values first one comes first(i.e P1 comes before P3)

I did the following

```
import collections
od = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True))
```

od gives

```
OrderedDict([('P2', 89), ('P3', 77), ('P1', 77)])
```

How can I get P1 before P3 ?

Comment: The premise of your question, that dictionaries themselves maintain order, is incorrect. For keys to be ordered, you need to use ordereddict from the start

Comment: I think you are right... That way it would work

Comment: You may wish to use the Sorted Collection [recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577197-sortedcollection/) to maintain a sorted collection rather than continuously sorting with new elements.

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
od = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key = lambda x:(-x[1],x[0])))
```

As @Padraic said, "You cannot sort from highest to lowest and lowest to highest." Therefore, you have to *trick* the sorted function by making it see the highest numbers as the lowest ones. It is sub-sorted by the natural order of the keys.

Answer (score 2):

Python's `sort` is a *stable* sort, meaning items stay in their original order if they compare equal.  If you start with an `OrderedDict` and just sort on the value only, they keys will stay in their original order.  In your case, however, sort them with a key that that sorts highest to lowest directly, instead of reversing the sort, to keep them in the same key order.

#### Example

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d = OrderedDict([('P1',77),('P2',89),('P3',77)])
print sorted(d.items(),key=lambda x:-x[1])
d = OrderedDict([('P3',77),('P2',89),('P1',77)])
print sorted(d.items(),key=lambda x:-x[1])
```

#### Output

```
[('P2', 89), ('P1', 77), ('P3', 77)]
[('P2', 89), ('P3', 77), ('P1', 77)]
```